# Keypress to change frames in As2

Tags: flash

I have 4 frames in my movie!

When the movie starts it will be on frame 1! When I press the space bar I want the next frame to be a random frame between 2,3 or 4! what code would I need for this? Im a beginner in flash & actionscript 2!

Comment: Also please note I do not want to create a button I want to do it when I press the space button!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
keyListener = new Object();
keyListener.onKeyDown = function() {
if (Key.getCode() == Key.SPACE){

    var random_number:Number = Math.random() * 3 + 1;
    trace('random_number is: ' + random_number);
    var nextFrame:Number = Math.ceil(random_number);
    trace('the next frame should be: ' + nextFrame);
    _root.gotoAndPlay(nextFrame);

    trace('you just hit the SPACE button');
    }
};
Key.addListener(keyListener);
```

Now you can put this code in the actions layer or in the first frame, where you should have a

```
stop();
```

command right before this code.

Comment: What layer do I put that on? I put it on the 1st frame but it says error! I also put it on my other layer called actions, but it also came up error?:/

Comment: You put this code in a button. You've created a button, right?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment now, about the button.

Comment: Did it both in each layer but still coming up as this error... Mouse events are permitted only for button instances
     on(keyPress "<Space>")

Comment: Ok cool, it dosent have any errors now, when I press the pace bar, it shows in the output "you just hit the SPACE button" but it dosent change frame? :/

Comment: I forgot to add the random part, I added it now :)

Comment: Its still doing the same thing? does not change frame always shows the circle which is my 1st frame, like my 2nd frame is square,3rd is triangle and 4th is octagon :/

Comment: What does trace(Math.random(3)+1)); print out for you? I don't have Flash installed here at work. Put this piece of code anywhere in the same frame.

Comment: It prints out the numbers below, every time I press it it changes the number but stays on the 1st frame... 1.60329446848482
1.06051784101874
1.01227758591995
1.33510967344046
1.17377293249592
1.76970039820299
1.89430847112089
1.57809857046232 when i put in any other frame it just quickly skips to that frame and then does nothing when pressed

Comment: Ok, instead of Math.random(3) use Math.random()*3 and it will work

Comment: And just to be sure, the entire command for that line should look like this : nextFrame = int(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

Comment: And what are the numbers it prints out? You used the `nextFrame = int(Math.random()*3 + 1);` line?

Comment: Ya I have copied the code at the top of this question that you have edited and placed it in the actions layer, error.... Type mismatch in assignment statement: found Number where Function is required.
         nextFrame = int(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

Comment: If it doesn't stop, just put `stop();` commands in frames 2,3,4.

Comment: still coming up as that error, it stays at the 1st frame and dosent move :/

Comment: I have another idea, try this : `nextFrame = Math.round(Math.random()*3 + 1);`

Comment: Type mismatch in assignment statement: found Number where Function is required.
      nextFrame = Math.round(Math.random()*3 + 1);

Comment: And it prints out only one number, right? The `trace(Math.random()*3 +1);` line.

Comment: Please edit the relevant information into the question and/or answer, or even post new answers with new details if that is warranted. The comment section of a question/answer is only meant for relevant information regarding the actual post at hand, like mistakes, requests for more details, etc. not for long discussions even though they may be helpful to the people involved. If you need to continue this discussion, consider taking it to a chat room instead.

Comment: I cant see what number it prints out because of the error? :/

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I tried moving to a chat room but he doesn't have enough reputation.

Comment: My last idea would be to use something like this: `random_frame = Math.random()*3 + 1;` `nextFrame = Math.round(random_frame);`

Comment: The first line of code works with no errors but still dosent change to the next image the numbers it prints out are 2.54113644035533
2.61855847900733
3.05117449676618
1.87338208546862
3.8383458009921 the 2nd line of code does not work :/

Comment: I edited the code in my answer, please try that and tell me the output.

Comment: **Error** Scene=Scene 1, layer=actions, frame=1:Line 8: Type mismatch in assignment statement: found Number where Function is required.
         nextFrame = Math.round(random_number);

Total ActionScript Errors: 1   Reported Errors: 1

Comment: `Math.ceil(random_number);` is one of my last guesses. Try this please.

Comment: No that didnt work either :/ Thanks for all your help though! Il keep at it here anyway! :)

Comment: Did it print out any numbers before the error? I'm curios if the problem is with the line that contains Math.round() or before it.

Comment: Ya when I used random_frame = Math.random()*3 + 1; it printed out the numbers 2.54113644035533 2.61855847900733 3.05117449676618 1.87338208546862 3.8383458009921 but stayed on the first frame?

Comment: Slight re-edit of answer, try it now please. I know it's kind of stressing trying all of these things.. I haven't used AS2 for 4-5 years now.

Comment: You legend! It works :) Thanks for being so help full, i have actually learnt alot now thanks to you :) Now since thats working I need to generate different pattern designs on each shapes :) Thats going to be another job haha! thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I've been working with Python, and if you ever come across it, you'll see that you never have to declare any types of variables. That's why I forgot to declare them as numbers :)

Comment: Oh ya iv used python to create a few 2d games :) Programming to me is very tough at times but it is very rewarding :)

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy: Just make a button instance that will not be seen (i.e., outside the stage bounds). You can make it a 1px by 1px button.

In the actions panel for THAT button, paste this code:

```
on(keyPress "<Space>"){
    nextFrame = Math.random()*3 + 1;
    _root.gotoAndPlay(nextFrame);
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to stop the movieclip initially at frame 1 using a `stop();`